# R: Converting data frame of percentages from factor to numeric

Tags: r

Running into issues converting a data frame into R.

I have a bunch of columns that were read as `factors` and have `%` symbols with them.

I know that for a single column I could do:

```
df[,3] <- as.numeric(sub("%","",df[,3]))
```

But trying to apply this to the whole dataset does not seem to work and changes all the values to NA. What am I doing wrong? Here is the code I tried to use:

```
df[,-1] <- as.numeric(sub("%","",df[,-1]))
```

**EDIT:** I know I can solve this with:

```
for (i in 2:66) {
df[,i] <- as.numeric(sub("%","",df[,i]))
print(class(df[,i]))
}
```

But there has to be a more elegant (and hopefully one-line) way to do this.

**EDIT 2:** Here is some of the data:

```
    Year        v1      v2       v3       v4
1 12-Oct        0%      0%      39%      14%
2 12-Nov        0%      6%      59%       4%
3 12-Dec       22%      0%      37%      26%
4 13-Jan       45%      0%      66%      19%
5 13-Feb       28%     39%      74%      13%
```

**ANSWERED:** Here is how I did it in one command after you all helped me so much! I was having problems with specifying the function part.

```
df=read.csv("all response rates.csv")
df[-1]<-data.frame(apply(df[-1], 2, function(x) 
    as.numeric(sub("%","",as.character(x)))))
```

Comment: If the percent sign is at the end of each string, try reading it in again with `comment.char = "%"`

Comment: When I do that, the first column of data is read correctly, but the other columns all become LOGI and are all NA.......what gives??

Comment: I dunno.  Show us some data :)

Comment: Will do @RichardScriven!

Comment: How about the first five lines of the file as well please

Comment: Isn't that what I just gave you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach using functions from `base`:

```
# dummy data:
df<-data.frame(v1=c("78%", "65%", "32%"), v2=c("43%", "56%", "23%"))

# function
df2<-data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) as.numeric(sub("%", "", x))) )
```

As per the comments provided this first strips away the percentage signs, and then converts the columns from factors to numeric.  I've changed the original answer from `apply` to `lapply` following @thelatemail's suggestions.

Comment: `lapply` is more appropriate, as it won't coerce to a matrix - something like `data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) as.numeric(sub("%", "", x))) )`

Comment: Not to mention that this answer is wrong and *not* converting factors to numeric, try `str(df2)`

Comment: @vashts85, the answer is 'strictly' wrong because the original didn't completely answer what was a two part question (because I didn't also wrap the sub in the `as.numeric()`) I've edited the answer to reflect this and @thelatemail's more helpful suggestion.

Answer (score 9):

`parse_number` from the `readr` package will remove the `%` symbols.  For your given data set, try:

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

res <- cbind(df %>% select(Year), # preserve the year column as-is
             df %>% select(-Year) %>% mutate_all(funs(parse_number))
             )

> res
    Year v1 v2 v3 v4
1 12-Oct  0  0 39 14
2 12-Nov  0  6 59  4
3 12-Dec 22  0 37 26
4 13-Jan 45  0 66 19
5 13-Feb 28 39 74 13
```

If you don't need to preserve your first column, you only need the excerpt:

```
df %>% select(-Year) %>% mutate_all(funs(parse_number))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option using `set` from `data.table`, which would be faster for big datasets as the overhead of `[.data.table` is avoided

```
library(stringi)
library(data.table)

setDT(df)
for(j in 2:ncol(df)){
     set(df, i=NULL, j=j, value= as.numeric(stri_extract(df[[j]], regex='\\d+')))
}

df
#     Year v1 v2 v3 v4
#1: 12-Oct  0  0 39 14
#2: 12-Nov  0  6 59  4
#3: 12-Dec 22  0 37 26
#4: 13-Jan 45  0 66 19
#5: 13-Feb 28 39 74 13
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a **one line** solution that assumes the data is in fixed width columns. I needed to remove the first row of names since all the columns did not have names. The widths of columns are specified as integers (with negative meaning to skip that many characters.) It also changes the column classes to numeric during the read.

```
your data

1 12-Oct        0%      0%      39%      14%
2 12-Nov        0%      6%      59%       4%
3 12-Dec       22%      0%      37%      26%
4 13-Jan       45%      0%      66%      19%
5 13-Feb       28%     39%      74%      13%

the R one-line script

adf <- read.fwf(file="a.dat",widths=c(-8,9,-1,7,-1,8,-1,8),colClasses=rep("numeric",4))

output result (first col provided by R to count the rows)

  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  0  0 39 14
2  0  6 59  4
3 22  0 37 26
4 45  0 66 19
5 28 39 74 13
```